# Knex silently converts Postgres timestamps with timezone and returns incorrect time

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js, bookshelf.js

I have a table in my psql database with a "trigger_time" column of type "TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT now()"

I data in the row is this `2018-06-27 15:45:00-03`.

When running from psql console

```
SELECT trigger_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' 
FROM tasks 
WHERE task_id = 1;
```

this query returns "2018-06-27 18:45:00".

Similarly when I run

```
SELECT trigger_time AT TIME ZONE 'America/Glace_Bay' 
FROM tasks 
WHERE task_id = 1;
```

I get `2018-06-27 15:45:00`

Using `knex.raw("SELECT trigger_time AT TIME ZONE 'America/Glace_Bay' FROM tasks WHERE task_id = 1")` I get `2018-06-27T18:45:00.000Z` and when running `knex.raw("SELECT trigger_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM tasks WHERE task_id = 1")` I get `2018-06-27T21:45:00.000Z`

Both of these results from knex are incorrect, how do I get knex to stop silently altering my data?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: I gave up, and had it return the time zone, and utc time separately and used moment.js to convert it to the correct time.

Answer (score 8):

Probably things are failing because when you are querying datetimes from database in certain timezone and effectively converting type of timestamp to be timestamp without timezone. In that case database will not send information to knex about in which timezone that returned time was.

So knex (or rather pg driver which knex is using) interprets your timestamp as local time, which depends of timezone setup of your application server running knex.

You could fetch time just as UTC and do timezone conversion in JavaScript side with moment or luxon libraries (IMO latter is better for timezone handling).

Other solution would be to tell pg driver that timestamp and timestamp with timezone types should not be converted to `JavaScript` `Date` objects.

It can be done like this (https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types):

```
const types = require('pg').types;
const TIMESTAMPTZ_OID = 1184;
const TIMESTAMP_OID = 1114;
types.setTypeParser(TIMESTAMPTZ_OID, val => val);
types.setTypeParser(TIMESTAMP_OID, val => val);
```

This code which makes all timestamps to be returned as strings may be added to for example in start of `knexfile.js`. Those returned strings will be exactly in the same format that they were returned by database server itself.

EDIT:

In code in the original post, when timestamp is converted to be in time zone `UTC` database server converts `timestamp with time zone` type to be normal `timestamp without time zone` so returned value doesn't have timezone information. To add timezone information back you can for example append +02 to the end of returned time stamp like this:

```
select ('2010-01-01T00:00:00.000Z'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')::text || '+00';
```

Which returns `2010-01-01 00:00:00+00` to the driver which can be read correctly by pg driver too.

This will effectively do the same thing that just setting `SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';` in db server when connection is created and just returning timestamptz column directly:

```
SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
select '2010-01-01T00:00:00.000+02:00'::timestamptz;
```

Which will return `2009-12-31 22:00:00+00`.

Comment: >>You could fetch time just as UTC and do timezone conversion in JavaScript side<<
<br>
I did just that and I was getting something three hours ahead of UTC. I am storing a separate string which has the timezone name (America/Glace_Bay)

Comment: @SpaceBear I do that all the time and I get correct values. Anyways you should do the trick above, which prevents pg driver from automatically converting timestamps to Date objects...

Comment: I agree its a sensible solution, but as you can see from my original question, even, when requesting the timestamp as UTC I get incorrect time values.

Comment: @SpaceBear yeah, thats just how postgresql works, when you request timestamp at time zone, postgresql converts returned type to be timestamp without timezone (at time zone 'UTC' is just like any other time zone).  I'll update answer to state that too.

Comment: OMG I spent so much time trying to figure this out. Thank you