# digitalocean nodejs app: knex is failing to connect to postgres, throwing timeout on a basic setup

Tags: node.js, postgresql, digital-ocean, knex.js

On digitalocean I setup a Nodejs app and add second component with PostgresDB. I can successfully ssh into the nodejs instance and connect to the DB via psql. But when I deploy the nodejs app, it throws me the famous knex.js error:

```
api         | 19:12:42     KnexTimeoutError: Knex: Timeout acquiring a connection. The pool is probably full. Are you missing a .transacting(trx) call?
```

I verified the postgres instance is completely fresh and has no pollution with idle connections by restarting a completely new instance and connecting via ssh / psql mentioned above and query:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity where datname='...';
```

with the right datname. I didn't see a single other connection besides the one established. Checking up on the params passed to the

```
const knex = require("knex")
const knexfile = require("./knexfile")
const { Model } = require("objection")

const db = knex(knexfile)
Model.knex(db)
```

I see that they're correct. I also checked older versions of packages for objection, knex and pg which are mentioned and thumbs-upped in one github issue [here](https://github.com/knex/knex/issues/2302#issuecomment-620628722). And I also tested with rolling back to Node v.12 instead of 14. No success.

Can you please help me understand what am I missing here?

**update** knexfile.js content:

```
const config = require("config")
const moment = require("moment")
const pg = require("pg")
const { knexSnakeCaseMappers } = require("objection")
const { parse } = require("pg-connection-string")
const pgConfig = parse(config.get("postgresql.url"))

const TIMESTAMPTZ_OID = 1184
pg.types.setTypeParser(TIMESTAMPTZ_OID, (val) =>
  val == null ? null : moment(val),
)

module.exports = {
  db: pgConfig,
  client: "postgresql",
  connection: {
    host: pgConfig.host,
    user: pgConfig.user,
    password: pgConfig.password,
    database: pgConfig.database,
  },
  acquireConnectionTimeout: 5 * 60 * 1000, // =5min
  debug: false,
  asyncStackTraces: process.env.NODE_ENV === "development",
  pool: {
    min: 2,
    max: 10,
  },
  ...knexSnakeCaseMappers(),
}
```

NOTE: for the timestamp timezone numeric values read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51082774/knex-silently-converts-postgres-timestamps-with-timezone-and-returns-incorrect-t) and [here](https://github.com/brianc/node-pg-types/pull/38).

NOTE 2: I also tested without mentioned timezone thing and the issue persists.

Comment: Please add contents of your knexfile.js (without sensitive data).

Comment: `I verified the postgres instance is completely fresh and has no pollution with idle connections by restarting a completely new instance and connecting via ssh / psql...` - How did you connect to DB with psql? Did you connect though unix socket or with TCP?  If not this might be the problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54067202/issues-with-postgres-authentication-during-integration-tests-with-docker/54071472#54071472

Comment: @MikaelLepistö a TCP connection exactly as in the comment under the link you provided.

Comment: Right...  then I have no idea what could be wrong there (unless your DB is not started yet when that error happens). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I received a mixed answers from the DigitalOcean technical support. They suggested to launch another app as a Droplet, not an "App", and use managed database instead of appending a component to the same "App" Component. The only assumption was indeed that the database component did not launch (or propagate) before the app. Now my setup has completely different issue not for this thread. Thank you @MikaelLepisto for an effort.